# Using keyboard alone, launch CMD with elevated privileges

Tags: command-line

Using the keyboard alone on Windows 7 or Windows 8, how can I open a privileged command prompt window with built-in tools?

I've unsucessfully tried Windows+R -> cmd -> runas /user:Administrator cmd
but the resulting cmd doesn't run with administrator privileges (due to UAC [explained here](https://superuser.com/questions/332354/windows-runas-command-with-elevated-privileges-user-in-admin-group))

I'm looking for a sudo equivalent essentially, without the mouse. [This is the best candidate](https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows/42540) I've seen thus far. Is that the best way currently?

Comment: I'd be surprised if there's a command-line based way that skips the UAC dialog. I thought that's kind of the intent - that no shell utility or anything that could run unseen can skip the prompt. It might be possible to have an administrative service running with startup, that can then start an administrative program though?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1029295/is-there-a-faster-way-to-open-a-process-as-administrator-with-uac-enabled/1029297#1029297

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Using keyboard alone, launch CMD with elevated privileges**
>
> Using the keyboard alone on Windows 7 or Windows 8, how can I open a
>   privileged command prompt window with built-in tools?

1. Press the <kbd>**Win Key**</kbd> | Type `CMD` in the search bar | Press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**Shift**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**Enter**</kbd>
2. If you have PowerShell installed you can run this command
   from <kbd>**Win Key**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**R**</kbd> . . . . . `Powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs"`

**Note:** *PowerShell is a Windows native built-in tool but it's optional so you have to have it installed for the #2 approach to work.  It is not third party though so it's a Microsoft Windows feature, tool, or shell.*

---

### **Sources**

- [`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` Method 1](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-elevated-command-prompt/)
- [`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` Method 2](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/command-prompt-administrator-shortcut/)
- [PowerShell Command - Run with elevated permissions](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-elevate.html)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> starts the Command Prompt (or Power Shell) as Admin under Windows 8.x and newer.